# Passing unique_ptr with derived class causes SEGFAULT

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, derived-class

could someone explain to me why executing function foo() here causes SEGFAULT? When I change the unique_ptr object in D class to contain B class object instead of A, everything works ok.

```
class A
{
    public:
    virtual void function() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    void function()
    {
        std::cout << "works!!";
    }
};

class D
{
    public:
    D(const std::unique_ptr<A>& arg): object(arg) {}

    void foo()
    {
        object->function();
    }

    private:
    const std::unique_ptr<A>& object;
};


int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> object = std::make_unique<B>();
    D d(std::move(object));

    d.foo();
}
```

I'm curious what's the logic behind it.

Comment: Since the types are not equal, a temporary unique pointer is created and you store a reference to a temporary.

Comment: Missing virtual destructor in `A` too.

Comment: The member `object` is a dangling reference.

Comment: Having `const std::unique_ptr<A>& object;` member is weird. Either `/*const*/ std::unique_ptr<A> object;` or `/*const*/ A& object;` seems better depending of intent.

Comment: If you feel the need to store a reference to a pointer in a class, then you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: [GotW#91](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-91-smart-pointer-parameters/) on how to pass smart pointers, and when, and why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You pass a *reference* to the smart pointer object. This smart pointer object will be destructed as soon ad the `d` object have been created. That leaves you with an invalid reference. When you try to use it, you will have *undefined behavior*.

Instead pass the pointer object *by value*, store it *by value* in the object, and *move* it into the object:

```
class D
{
public:
    D(std::unique_ptr<A> arg): object(std::move(arg)) {}

    // ...

    std::unique_ptr<A> object;
};
```